# iphone, my AVPlayer player is playing video really fast

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, avplayer

My application is using AVPlayer to play video. There is a serious problem that my app currently experience. Sometimes, it is playing the video very fast although I checked to make sure that I either set the `self.player.rate = 0.3` or `self.player.rate = 1` or not set the rate at all. This only happens sometimes and it happens to all the videos I have.

Can anyone give me any hint on the current problem?

Comment: Can you say when it sometimes plays very fast? Is it reproducible?

Comment: Did you tried to clean all the targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally know the answer. I called `[player setRate:0.3]` and `[player play]` at the same time and the second call override the first call, which sets the rate to be 0 (normal). The method `setRate:` already set the rate for the player and play the video already